# gnome-disks Partition Type mismatch on IDE drive - not allowing mount

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, gnome-disk-utility

I have an old IDE hard drive whose contents I'm trying to backup.

I connected the hard drive to my PC, running Ubuntu 23.10, via a USB/IDE adapter, the hard drive's capacity (80 GB) is correctly recognized. The drive is from 2003 which AFAIK predates SMART, because when I try to run:

```
sudo smartctl -d sat --all /dev/sda
```

it doesn't return any SMART data: `Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode`

To make things worse, `gnome-disks` seems to have difficulty getting the correct Partition type.

[image: /dev/sda partition info in gparted]
[image: first partition of /dev/sda info]

It lists the partition type as `0x4D`. This is supposed to mean ["QNX 4.x"](https://github.com/caldwell/gdisk/blob/master/partition-type.c#L106)

So I loaded the `qnx4` module and then assumed I could mount it.

But if I then try to pass the `qnx4` option to `mount`:

```bash
sudo mount -t qnx4 /dev/sda /media/ReplayTV
```

It fails:

```
mount: /media/ReplayTV: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

If the partition type was correct, shouldn't it have been able to correctly mount and not claimed the fs type was wrong?

Comment: SMART goes back to 1992; though wasn't common on drives before 1995; though cheaper drives built into external-cases (for external use) didn't include SMART capacity until much later. If the drive is from 2003; it should have SMART (*unless it was a cheap consumer drive built into external case & not intended for internal use inside a computer*)  If this drive is taken from a non-computer box (eg. NAS/media player etc), they sometimes *slightly* corrupt the partition table to intentionally block what you're trying to do.

Comment: As a workaround, seeing 1TB >>> 80GB, you can always do a block-based instead of file-based backup: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/root/mybackup.dat`

Comment: `sudo mount -t qnx4 /dev/sda2 /media/ReplayTV` - note **2**, would be more correct for mounting the second partition (the one selected in the last image)

Comment: Maybe also try `udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sda2` which would mount it the same style as when a device (e.g. sd-card) auto-mounts.